# fetching json data in the controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

With the command `console.log($scope.data)` I can see my json file. I can also see the whole items in the view with `<div ng-repeat="item in data">` but `console.log($scope.data[0])` or `console.log($scope.data[0].name)` return an error `"undefined"`and `console.log($scope.data.length)` return 0.How can I access the items in the controller.
**edit**
$scope.data contain a json file. `$scope.data = service.query();` and it looks like [image]
I don't understand why is length return 0 when ng-repeat is working

Comment: Can you add the output you get with console.log($scope.data) ?

Comment: We need to know the format of your data structure. Please post the json etc

Comment: whats your json look like?

Comment: You are trying to access it like an array, when I assume it's not. I can't say much else till I see the JSON.

Comment: Is $scope.data a string, array, or object?

Comment: @JonathonBlok, the fact user567 can `ng-repeat` but can't access it via indexes, leads me to believe it's an object.

Comment: True. Though, I was thrown off by $scope.data.length returning 0. If it's an object, it should return undefined?

Comment: It sounds like your code is trying to access the data before it has been received from the server If you're still stuck,, show us the actual code instead of snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you've stripped down all the relevant details (e.g. `service.query` implementation) from the question.

This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OXvezsamrTTtk9sBJ32I) may shed some light on what's going on.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.factory('data', function ($timeout) {
  var data = [];

  return {
    query: function () {
      $timeout(function () {
        data.push(1, 2, 3);
      }, 1000);

      setTimeout(function () {
        data.push('Oops, ng-repeat is unconscious of this one');
      }, 2000);

      return data;
    }
  };
});

app.controller('AppController', function($scope, data) {
  $scope.data = {
    agile: [1, 2, 3],
    lazy: data.query()
  };

  $scope.$watch('data.lazy', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal === oldVal) return;
    console.log($scope.data.lazy[0]);
  }, true);
});
```